# Response is encoded somehow?

Tags: postman

I am new with Postman, so bare over with me if the answer is obvious. I am trying to simulate a facebook request. So I go to crome and find the request in the developer tool and click copy curl:

```
curl 'https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/' -H 'origin: https://www.facebook.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,da-DK;q=0.8,da;q=0.7,und;q=0.6' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://www.facebook.com/pg/KotaSchuetz/photos/?ref=page_internal' -H 'authority: www.facebook.com' -H 'cookie: dpr=2; datr=YeRHXauuPweQJ5Y9_hZALUiq; sb=ZeRHXepAsanc2lyq01n6t23u; _fbp=fb.1.1564993022377.743027707; locale=da_DK; wd=1050x922; fr=1lIqKU0zJAQIo53kV.AWVl5Lq64t5KT28UV1IDdZPTDcI.BdR-Rj.aX.F1H.0.0.BdR-jk.AWVxxFkJ' --data 'av=0&__user=0&__a=1&__dyn=7xeUmFoHw_Jxl0BCwDKEyGgS8USQjFCwloS2Sq5-axubwTwywTxqbyQdxK5WAxacyUuKcUfFU9EgzoS2Sih6UXwCg898Gicx21LxiUd8hwj8lwCAx2i10GfzEWq686yl0Dwxzo8ofHG3q5U4aE4a3mbzUeU-1dx3ximfVEW8wRK4ovyp8rAUG2GXxK8wDxC5oOEiKm2e14zU4G8xGErxCcyE9XAy8aElxWWzU4K8DwGy85i5o9kbxSu68vwlo9oow8m2WE9EjwaO&__req=n&__be=1&__pc=PHASED%3ADEFAULT&dpr=2&__rev=1001018175&__s=%3Aa1kp7i%3A4ymz6z&__hsi=6721596602655958753-0&lsd=AVr5P4v6&jazoest=2622&__spin_r=1001018175&__spin_b=trunk&__spin_t=1564993663&fb_api_caller_class=RelayModern&fb_api_req_friendly_name=PagePhotosTabAllPhotosGridPaginationQuery&variables=%7B%22count%22%3A28%2C%22cursor%22%3A%22AQHRY8pI2Gl64JePNDFCnYYzMZ-_vkWFc4R3L5fSQ5N0u62K0R68giUtxgLUZ7hZVGIOJ3B79Tu-3WHFO8N6jJSARw%22%2C%22pageID%22%3A%22200168320060101%22%7D&doc_id=1887586514672506' --compressed
```

Then I import it into Postman. It seems like headers etc are copied as expected to postman. However I get following response? Any pointers, is it some https certificate thing i need to configure?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the headers? They should contain the info what type of data is that. Because, well, you didn't specify what type you're expecting (`'accept: */*'`) and it may be anything.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I added headers in main post.

Comment: Headers of the response, please. We already see the headers of your request in the example curl. :P

Comment: :D Added in org post :D

Comment: It also looks like Chrome dosent provide the method type (GET/POST) in the curl.